# getting error nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: compositKey of:

Tags: hibernate

I am getting error that

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: 
compositKey of: com.thetasp.tu.data.TuSegCreditExposure 
[from com.thetasp.tu.data.TuSegCreditExposure c where c.compositKey.rptRefNo=? and 
c.ic=?]
```

here i am making query and getting exception

```
public List<Object> findSegObjByRptRefNo(String rptRefNo, Class className,
        String[] fields, String[] values) {
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    String sql = "from " + className.getName() + " c 
        where c.compositKey.rptRefNo=?";
    buff.append(sql);

    if (fields != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            String field = fields[i];
            buff.append(" and c." + field + "=?");
        }
    }

    Object[] argument = new Object[values.length + 1];
    argument[0] = rptRefNo;

    for (int i = 1; i <= values.length; i++) {
        argument[i] = values[i - 1];
        System.out.println(argument[i]);
    }

    try {

        List<TuSegCreditExposure> exList = getHibernateTemplate().find(
                buff.toString(), argument);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String message = e.getMessage();
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }

    return getHibernateTemplate().find(buff.toString(), argument);
}
```

This line gives me error

```
List<TuSegCreditExposure> exList = getHibernateTemplate().find(buff.toString(), 
                                                       argument);
```

Why i am getting this error.

Here is my TuSegCreditExposueclass

```
public class TuSegCreditExposure extends AbstractArchivableObj implements Serializable {

private TuSegCompositeKey compositeKey;
private String totalAccountsRevolv;
    ....
```

}

Please tell me why i am getting this exception. What i am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try debugging the code what is `c.id` in the error message. Is it there in the table.

Comment: @pKs `c.id` or `c.ic` ?

Comment: @pKs I have table Tu_Seg_Credit_Exposure in which i have both fields rptRefNo and ic. Actually in table the columns are rpt_ref_No and I_C

Comment: @pKs the query is right, the values are right like the query is `from com.thetasp.tu.data.TuSegCreditExposure c where c.compositKey.rptRefNo=? and c.ic=?` and when i run the query in the sqlDeveloper like `select * from Tu_Seg_Credit_Exposure c where c.rpt_Ref_No= '12345' and c.i_c = 'I';`, then the result is there.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
String sql = "from " + className.getName() + " c 
    where c.compositeKey.rptRefNo=?";
```

rather than `compositKey`, see missing e in `composit` :)

Thanks